# Optimal SIMD algorithm to rotate or transpose an array

Tags: assembly, intel, simd, transpose, avx2

I am working on a data structure where I have an array of 16 uint64. They are laid out like this in memory (each below representing a single int64):

```
A0 A1 A2 A3 B0 B1 B2 B3 C0 C1 C2 C3 D0 D1 D2 D3
```

The desired result is to transpose the array into this:

```
A0 B0 C0 D0 A1 B1 C1 D1 A2 B2 C2 D2 A3 B3 C3 D3
```

The rotation of the array 90 degrees is also an acceptable solution for the future loop:

```
D0 C0 B0 A0 D1 C1 B1 A1 D2 C2 B2 A2 D3 C3 B3 A3
```

I need this in order to operate on the arrow fast at a later point (Traverse it sequentially with another SIMD trip, 4 at a time).

So far, I have tried to "blend" the data by loading up a 4 x 64 bit vector of A's, bitmaskising and shuffling the elements and OR'ing it with B's etc and then repeating that for C's... Unfortunately, this is 5 x 4 SIMD instructions per segment of 4 elements in the array (one load, one mask, one shuffle, one or with next element and finally a store). It seems I should be able to do better.

I have AVX2 available and I a compiling with clang.

Comment: `C1 C1` is this a typo? Please show the correct output.

Comment: Sorry, typo...Yes, I want to transpose the matrix (rotate it 90 degrees)

Comment: Let me see if I understand your question. You want to transpose a 4x4 matrix of uint64?

Comment: @Zboson: Yes, that is another way of viewing it.

Comment: Transpose is *not* the same as rotation by 90 degrees - based on your example it looks like you want the former rather than the latter.

Comment: @PaulR: You are right. Actually, I can use either a 90 rotation or a transpose. I will update the question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
uint64_t A[16] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15};
__m256i row0 = _mm256_loadu_si256((__m256i*)&A[ 0]); //0 1 2 3
__m256i row1 = _mm256_loadu_si256((__m256i*)&A[ 4]); //4 5 6 7
__m256i row2 = _mm256_loadu_si256((__m256i*)&A[ 8]); //8 9 a b
__m256i row3 = _mm256_loadu_si256((__m256i*)&A[12]); //c d e f
```

I don't have hardware to test this on right now but something like the following should do what you want

```
__m256i tmp3, tmp2, tmp1, tmp0;
tmp0 = _mm256_unpacklo_epi64(row0, row1);            //0 4 2 6
tmp1 = _mm256_unpackhi_epi64(row0, row1);            //1 5 3 7
tmp2 = _mm256_unpacklo_epi64(row2, row3);            //8 c a e
tmp3 = _mm256_unpackhi_epi64(row2, row3);            //9 d b f
//now select the appropriate 128-bit lanes
row0 = _mm256_permute2x128_si256(tmp0, tmp2, 0x20);  //0 4 8 c
row1 = _mm256_permute2x128_si256(tmp1, tmp3, 0x20);  //1 5 9 d
row2 = _mm256_permute2x128_si256(tmp0, tmp2, 0x31);  //2 6 a e
row3 = _mm256_permute2x128_si256(tmp1, tmp3, 0x31);  //3 7 b f
```

The

```
__m256i _mm256_permute2x128_si256 (__m256i a, __m256i b, const int imm)
```

intrinsic selects 128-bit lanes from two sources. You can read about it in [the Intel Intrinsic Guide](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/). There is a version `_mm256_permute2f128_si256` which only needs AVX and acts in the floating point domain. I used this to check that I used the correct control words.

Comment: +1: nice transpose - I fixed a few minor bugs in the code and comments and it's now tested and verified on a Haswell CPU.

Comment: @Zboson: This is an awesome solution. 8 instructions! I wonder if it can be done in less with a 90 degree rotate (which is also an acceptable layout of the destination array)

Answer (score 4):

An alternative is to use the *gather* instructions, you can load directly the transposed matrix. The five lines of code below are ok with gcc on a i7-Haswell.

```
  int32_t stride = 4 * sizeof(A[0]);
  __m128i r128_gather_idx = _mm_set_epi32(3 * stride, 2 * stride, 1 * stride, 0 * stride);
  __m256i row0 = _mm256_i32gather_epi64(reinterpret_cast<long long const *>(&A[ 0]), r128_gather_idx, 1);
  __m256i row1 = _mm256_i32gather_epi64(reinterpret_cast<long long const *>(&A[ 1]), r128_gather_idx, 1);
  __m256i row2 = _mm256_i32gather_epi64(reinterpret_cast<long long const *>(&A[ 2]), r128_gather_idx, 1);
```

Comment: On Haswell, gather provides functionality, but not much performance (this may change on future µarches, of course).  Basically, anytime you can do the same operation with fixed permutes, you should do so.

Comment: I saw about a 2x slowdown on the gather vs. the fixed permute. So @Zbosons answer is the fastest. Nice to have this for completeness though.

Comment: I did not think of using gather. That's an interesting idea.